# Custom "Next" Buttons for Spring MVC AbstractWizardFormController

Tags: spring, spring-mvc, spring-security

Currently, a spring application I am working on has several wizards that it is using with Spring's AbstractWizardFormController. During the early stages of development(pre-design phase), the type of "next" button did not matter.

Just to refresh, the **Next** and **Back** button are submit buttons with **target** attributes. So a next button on the first page of a wizard would look like the following.

```
<input type="submit" name="_target1" value="Next"/>
```

This is the standard way Spring does wizards on the view. This works fine, given that you want your **Next** button to be a standard HTML submit button. Otherwise, in my case, If I want a custom button, I am not sure how to do this. I know it is possible, but haven't found any documentation.

I imagine I will need to do a javascript submit, but I am not sure how to set the name of the button, of if something else needs to be done.

I just need to know how I can still extend AbstractWizardFormController, and use custom buttons.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When clicked, HTML submit button submits a form with additional parameter `{name}={value}`, that is `_target1=Next`. I guess the value doesn't matter here, controller looks at the name. So, if you want to emulate this with Javascript, you may, for example, dynamically add a hidden field with `name = "_target1"` before submit.

Comment: I have actually seen something like this I believe. I like this idea though, thanks!